# Installing PyOpenGL with MacPorts

Tags: python, macports, pyopengl

I'm trying to install PyOpenGL with macports, and I'd like to use Python 2.7, which I have also installed with macports. However, only Python 2.4 seems to have access to PyOpenGL when I install it with: `sudo port install py-opengl`

Anyone know what is going on? How can I get python 2.7 to see PyOpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sudo port py27-opengl` instead.

In general, with MacPorts python-related ports, the Python version to which it applies is encoded in its name: `py25-`, `py26-`, `py27-`, `py31-`, `py32-`.  They started doing this after Python 2.4, so `py-` are generally the legacy Python 2.4 versions.  There are other ports that use variants to select which Python to link with.  These are called out in the port descriptions, like [these](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=variant&substr=python27).  For example, to install `boost` for Python 2.7, you would use `sudo port boost +python27`.

Comment: Ah, right, of course... dunno why I didn't see those when I searched. Thanks!